# Passing Details From One Window to Another Window

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, selectionchanged

I have a selection of `TextBoxes` that a user fills in when they wish to note that they have had contact with another person. Most of the `TextBoxes` are imply filled in by typing into them. However, for one of them I would like the user to be able to select from a list of `People` that appears when they click on a button.

This is where I am having problems. So far I have just made a `DataGrid` appear and handled it's `SelectionChanged` method to fill in the `TextBoxes` text property. This has worked fine, however now there is not enough space on the current page to show an entire `DataGrid` with all the people they can select from.

I've decided to show the `People` in a separate, smaller `Window` that appears when the user clicks a `Button`.  The issue I have is that when the user selects the `Person` they wish to mark the contact for in the new `Window`, I have no idea how I can notify the original `Window` that a `Person` has been selected, close the new smaller `Window` and fill in the appropriate `TextBox` on the original `Window`.

What would be the most intuitive way to fill in the `TextBox` on the original `Window`, based on the selection on the `Window` that opens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use delegates,which call a function of the original window and parse the changed variable with it. So you know when the user clicked something and you can directly react to this "event".

Link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you use a framework like Galasoft's MVVM Light (http://www.galasoft.ch/), they have a messenger system just for this purpose.  It allows you to "broadcast" messages that can be "received" by any other part of the application

Answer (score 0):

This is when considering using Domain, Model, Presentation (Winforms/WPF version of MVC formatting) to do your app.

You can have each form as its own class, well they are their own class.  Create each form class but add some public members to it if the controls are private.  Have them have "get" properties only and to return the values of whatever controls or variables are in that form.  Your main form will be the controlling form.  All forms will be handled by the main form so when you open it, it is a class the main form can access.

Now, if I remember (been doing more MVC and not any Winforms lately) I believe if you use the ShowDialog() method it will freeze the main thread so when you close out the main form you can continue and read in public members you have in your forms class you opened.  Synchronous I believe it runs as.  If you use just Show() the thread will keep on trucking, asynchronous.  With asynchronous you may then have to use a main form in your startup code so there is always a window there but subscribe to the close event of your forms and have a method that can grab those public members out.  Be sure to instantiate the extra forms at the root of the main class so it doesn't fall out of scope when it exists the method that calls it.  You may even be able to make the method that calls is a async call and have an await before the command that runs the Show method on the form.

Summary, treat each form as its own class but add public members that can read the values from the controls and/or variables you want.  Read that data from the class when it closes via an event or synchronously when the thread closes out from the form closing.  The form closing doesn't discard the object, just the visualization of the form.

Oh, if you are passing info from the main form to a child for you are opening, either add a constructor for that form class that takes your input as a model or values to fill in the appropriate variables or forms before showing it or create a public property you can put your values you want to send in before showing the class.

Remember, everything is a class, once you look at it as such and treat it as such, the answer will come.  :-)

I should warn, I am a long winded explainer.

At work putting all this down from memory so some errors may exist.  Let me know if there are.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is to access the controls of the main window, isn`t it?
You can define an event of changing user`s choise and access MainWindow control by using the following construction:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).MyTextBox
```